# Text manipulation of macro list variables to stack datasets with automated names

Tags: sas

I have written a macro that accepts a list of variables, runs a proc mixed model using each variable as a predictor, and then exports the results to a dataset with the variable name appended to it. I am trying to figure out how to stack the results from all of the variables in a single data set.

Here is the macro:

```
%macro cogTraj(cog,varlist);
    %let j = 1;
    %let var = %scan(&varlist, %eval(&j));
    %let solution = sol;
    %let outsol = &solution.&var.;

        %do %while (&var ne );

                proc mixed data = datuse;
                model &cog = &var  &var*year  /solution cl;
                random int year/subject = id;
                ods output SolutionF = &outsol;
                run;

        %let j = %eval(&j + 1);
        %let var = %scan(&varlist, %eval(&j));
        %let outsol = &solution.&var.;
        %end;

%mend;


   /* Example */
   %cogTraj(mmmscore, varlist = bio1 bio2 bio3);
```

The result would be the creation of Solbio1, Solbio2, and Solbio3.

I have created a macro variable containing the "varlist" (Ideally, I'd like to input a macro variable list as the argument but I haven't figured out how to deal with the scoping):

```
%let biolist = bio1 bio2 bio3;
```

I want to stack Solbio1, Solbio2, and Solbio3 by using text manipulation to add "Sol" to the beginning of each variable. I tried the following, outside of any data step or macro:

```
 %let biolistsol = %add_string( &biolist, Sol, location = prefix);
```

without success.

Ultimately, I want to do something like this;

```
    data Solbio_stack;
    set %biolistsol;
    run;
```

with the result being a single dataset in which Solbio1, Solbio2, and Solbio3 are stacked, but I'm sure I don't have the right syntax.

Can anyone help me with the text string/dataset stacking issue? I would be extra happy if I could figure out how to change the macro to accept %biolist as the argument, rather than writing out the list variables as an argument for the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this differently.  A good approach for the problem is to drive it with a dataset; that's what SAS is good at, really, and it's very easy.

First, construct a dataset that has a row for each variable you're running this on, and a variable `name` that contains the variable name (one per row).  You might be able to construct this using `PROC CONTENTS` or `sashelp.vtable` or `dictionary.tables`, if you're using a set of variables from one particular dataset.  It can also come from a spreadsheet you import, or a text file, or anything else really - or just written as datalines, as below.

So your example would have this dataset:

```
data vars_run;
input name $ cog $;
datalines;
bio1 mmmscore
bio2 mmmscore
bio3 mmmscore
;;;;
run;
```

If your 'cog' is fairly consistent you don't need to put it in the data, if it is something that might change you might also have a variable for it in the data.  I do in the above example include it.

Then, you write the macro so it does one pass on the `PROC MIXED` - ie, the inner part of the `%do` loop.

```
%macro cogTraj(cog=,var=, sol=sol);
     proc mixed data = datuse;
      model &cog = &var  &var*year  /solution cl;
      random int year/subject = id;
      ods output SolutionF = &sol.&var.;
     run;
%mend cogTraj;
```

I put the default for &sol in there.  Now, you generate one call to the macro from each row in your dataset.  You also generate a list of the sol sets.

```
proc sql;
 select cats('%cogTraj(cog=',cog,',var=',name,',sol=sol)')
  into :callList
  sepearated by ' '
  from have;
 select cats('sol',name') into :solList separated by ' '
   from have;
quit;
```

Next, you run the macro:

```
&callList.
```

And then you can do this:

```
data sol_all;
 set &solList.;
run;
```

All done, and a lot less macro variable parsing which is messy and annoying.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer and showing me some new things! I'm a native R programmer so I often fail to harness SAS's strengths and try to do things the "R" way.

Comment: I would suggest that you forget the macro language for a while, then.  The macro language is not the 'programming' piece of SAS.  You can do most things the R way using SAS data step code, I think you'll find, only using macros the way I do above (to contain some code you will be repeating).  Handle the repeats with data.  This is basically doing `lapply`, give or take, after all, and the macro is just the inline function you're `lapplying`.

Comment: Additionally, if you have SAS/IML licensed, that might be easier to transition to - that is a matrix language similar to R.  (`proc iml;` to start it).

Comment: Finally, if you like writing functions, there is `proc fcmp` if you have 9.3 or newer (or maybe 9.2, I forget).  It's not necessarily as efficient as functions you'd write in R, but it is nice for compartmentalizing things.